# Facebook Developers Adding Allowed Domains for JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, subdomain, facebook-javascript-sdk, wildcard-subdomain

I am reaching out to seek assistance regarding the configuration of Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK in our app, Azle. As you may know, Azle is a customer support application that integrates with Facebook, and we are currently working on implementing the Facebook login feature using the Facebook SDK.

One requirement for the smooth integration is to add the Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK in the app's configuration. However, as Azle assigns a unique subdomain to each user upon signup, we need to dynamically add these subdomains to the Allowed Domains list for proper functionality.

Could you kindly provide guidance on how to accomplish this task? We want to ensure that when users log in with their Facebook accounts through the SDK, their assigned subdomains are recognized as allowed domains by Facebook.

We have thoroughly reviewed the Facebook documentation but could not find specific instructions for dynamically adding Allowed Domains. We are eager to adhere to Facebook's policies and guidelines while maintaining the security and privacy of our users' data.

Comment: This really looks and feels like spam but I guess it is actually asking a legit question. Drop all the blabla about your product, remove the greeting, etc. and just ask a question please. The last three and the first two paragraphs should be deleted in their entirety. Or this warrants a legit spam flag.

Comment: i have remove greeting.

Comment: `app_domains` is one of the field you can update via a POST request. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/#parameters-3

Comment: I have added in app domains but it's not working.